# C++ Array Sort - problem accounting for "bbba" and "0001" as incorrect sorts

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, logic

```
 //is the array ordered?
    //if there are one or zero elements, inherently sorted
    //can't compare to other elements if they don't exist
    if ( len == 0 || len ==1 )
    {
        return true;
        cout<<"isOrdered"<<endl;
    }
    //if more than 1 element <> can do a comparison
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
          if ( sArr[i] > sArr[i+1])
          {
            return false;
            cout<<"notOrdered"<<endl;
          }
          else if (sArr[i]<=sArr[i+1])
            {
              return true; //here it must be ordered.
            }
    }
```

}

sort logic taken from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-check-array-sorted-not-iterative-recursive/

This code is in a larger function, which turns strings and unsigned ints into arrays, and checks if the order of elements is ASCII ordered from lowest to highest.

Problem is that it does not treat "abba" or "111110" as not ordered cases. 
it continually returns true for cases like this and I don't understand why. 
Doesn't the code compare element by element to the one right next to it?

Comment: Your loop never goes beyond first iteration, because you always `return` from the function in it.

Comment: Your code returns as soon as it compares `sArr[0]` with `sArr[1]`, since both conditions have a return statement.   To detect either of those cases as not-ordered, it is necessary to loop again and check subsequent characters rather than returning `true`.

Comment: Thank you, will try it out.

Comment: You do know `std::sort` exists - right?

Comment: well I'm doing this, because I can't use sort. ie. for an assignment.

Comment: so the problem is with the  else if (sArr[i]<=sArr[i+1]) . to loop to check the next character, how does adding another for loop help. --- for (int i=last; i<len; i++) { if (sArr[i]<=sArr[i+1] ) return true;  else if (sArr[i]>sArr[i+1] return false;

Comment: @ThermoRestart - that doesn't fix the problem, as it doesn't change the fact of the function immediately returning from the first iteration.

Comment: @ThermoRestart:  Review the three answers, all of them solve the problem.  An extra loop is not needed.  You only have to wait until after the for loop is completed to return the true case.  Choose one and accept it.  Good luck and happy programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to test for 0 or 1 at start (since the for loop already has the `i<len` condition and will be false for both 0 and 1) but you do need to move the `return true` out of the loop. You don't know that it's sorted until you've compared all elements:

```
for(int i=1; i<len; ++i) {
    if(sArr[i-1] > sArr[i]) return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

from your code, you need to return at least there is one out of order and then need to return true when all are okay.

** also need to run only till (length -1)

```
for (int i=0; i<len-1; i++)
{
      if ( sArr[i] > sArr[i+1])
      {
        cout<<"notOrdered"<<endl;
        return false;
      }
}
cout<<"isOrdered"<<endl;
return true;
```

Comment: Your `std::cout <<` calls will never execute.

Comment: you still have one that won't execute :-)

Answer (score 0):

Testing for 0 and 1 is a good idea in the recursive case.  This function could be called recursively, so you can leave that out.  You have left out the recursion and used a for loop instead.  Here is the corrected code, which waits until after the for loop to return true if the current pairs are sorted correctly.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool IsArraySorted(int sArr[], int len)
{
  //is the array ordered?

  //if more than 1 element <> can do a comparison
  for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    if (sArr[i] > sArr[i + 1]) {
      cout << "notOrdered" << endl; // call before return :-)

      return false;
    }
  }
  cout << "Ordered" << endl;

  return true; //here it must be ordered.

}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo: thank you.  The original code OP looked at was recursive, which is why it had to check for 0 and 1 element arrays.  Taking that out, I messed that up.

Comment: One minor nitpick: using `i = 0; i < len - 1` instead of `i = 1; i < len` adds an unnecessary subtraction.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Right again!  Your answer is the better one.  Even if I set up a termination value prior to the for loop (which would avoid the subtraction on every loop), I would still have one more subtraction than your answer.